# How to add RANDOM setting in Foundation 5's Orbit Slider?

Tags: javascript, random, zurb-foundation, orbit

Pretty self explanatory, I want to add a 'random' option to Orbit Slider. A lot of people are asking this question but there are few useful answers.

I've looked through this site and even on Foundation's site and I can't find anything of an answer for this version of Orbit. With that said, I did find a page here on StackOverFlow here: [jQuery Orbit - How to make a Random Slideshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177967/jquery-orbit-how-to-make-a-random-slideshow) I believe this to be a solution to my issue, however the version of Orbit it was meant to work with is out dated and I'm not sure how to go about doing that to the updated Orbit 5.2.2. I can sort-of understand JS, but I'm not at a point where I can break it down and write it.

My question, then, is how to rewrite that code for the new version of Orbit?

Thanks in advance, all answers are helpful!

Closest answer I could find: [jQuery Orbit - How to make a Random Slideshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177967/jquery-orbit-how-to-make-a-random-slideshow)

Link to Foundation 5 Orbit: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) there is already github page https://github.com/zurb/orbit use the **randomize_slides** branch.

branch of the link : https://github.com/zurb/orbit/tree/randomize_slides

**randomize default object line** https://github.com/zurb/orbit/blob/randomize_slides/jquery.orbit-1.3.0.js#L31

**download github branch demo** https://github.com/zurb/orbit/archive/randomize_slides.zip

best regards.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for sharing this information with me and I'm grateful for your time. I can use this version of Orbit slider in place of the new one, but I'm curious if you could look into using this code in the new Orbit? I'm not very great with JS, it seems as if they rewrote everything. If not, again its okay haha

Comment: so; I'm always helps.